# Starting another app inside my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start an app that is shown inside my app. At the moment I just start another app over mine with

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.getAppID());
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

That works good, but I'd like to let the user know, my app is still in the background. With a colored frame for instance. I thought of loading the new app inside a fragment like with iframes in HTML but could not find a way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on Android, sorry.

Each app runs in its own process, and there is no way to run one inside another like an iframe.

Comment: I already guessed its not possible, but wanted to give it a shot. Thanks for the quick answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing applications with activities.

You can run a shared activity in your application but not the entire application. So this would greatly depend on what you are trying to do.